# I submitted and then updated submission but now the app is just unavailable

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, windows-store, submission

I have submitted my app 3 days ago and It was successfully uploaded to the store and people could download it. yesterday I updated submission (I have changed the description and the store logo), and it was successfully uploaded on the store. But it is only shown in the [store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/georgian-petroleum/9nblggh5jjn3) correctly. when I click it, it redirect to the store application on my windows phone but shows the 'old' app with old logo and description and with the error message that it is not available [image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/105485096/store.jpg). What happened and how can I fix this problem?

Comment: I think the problem may be that you updated your WP 8.1 app to the new Windows 10 app. Then the app is not available on WP 8.1 devices, but on Windows 10 devices it is. Have you only changed the descritpion and the logo or have you uploaded a new package?

Comment: I uploaded new package too

Comment: @KristianVukusic I uploaded package too but it says windows phone 8.1 above the package. any idea please? :(

Answer (score 0):

It might time some time for the Windows Store modifications to spread. If you still face the same problem within 24h, contact the Windows Store Developer Support

https://dev.windows.com/support